# How to run Selenium Brave web browser webdriver in c#?

Tags: webdriver

Someone kind can help me with this.
I have a problem and it is that I cannot run Selenium in Brave with visual studio. Can someone help me on the code? What would it be to execute it? Because with the visual studio webdriver automatically running chrome, I want to tell it to run Brave. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements:**

- Install Nuget Packages (**Selenium.Webdriver**, **Selenium.Chrome.Webdriver**)

```cs
private string chromeDriverPath = @"C:\Path\To\chromedriver.exe"; //Path to chromedriver.exe
private string braveBrowserPath = @"C:\Path\To\brave.exe"; //Path to brave.exe

private ChromeOptions chromeOptions; //Default value of chromeOptions is null
private IWebDriver driver; //Default value of driver is null

public void LoadChrome() {
    try
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath); //Sets process evnironment
        chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions(); //Initialize chromeOptions
        chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = braveBrowserPath; //Sets the location of Brave
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); //Initialize driver with chromeOptions
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); //Set Brave window maximized
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/"); //Loads page Google
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //Print any errors to console log
    }
}
```

[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) seems to be pretty easy to use. You can take a look at their [API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) and [Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started/) that include usages and examples with C# programming language.

There is also a [cheat sheet](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/selenium-webdriver-csharp-cheat-sheet/) you can use for reference in case you're too lazy to look up API or Documentation.